# How to add drawable to a Text in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As in XML we used to add a drawable to a `TextView`, so What is the equivalent of `android:drawableLeft`, `android:drawableRight` in Jetpack Compose `Text`? Is there any easy way to achieve this other than using `Row { Image() Text() }`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, until `rc01` Compose does not provide this feature.
I was able to achieve a similar result using `ConstraintLayout`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DrawableWrapper(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @DrawableRes drawableTop: Int? = null,
    @DrawableRes drawableStart: Int? = null,
    @DrawableRes drawableBottom: Int? = null,
    @DrawableRes drawableEnd: Int? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier) {
        val (refImgStart, refImgTop, refImgBottom, refImgEnd, refContent) = createRefs()
        Box(Modifier.constrainAs(refContent) {
            top.linkTo(drawableTop?.let { refImgTop.bottom } ?: parent.top)
            bottom.linkTo(drawableBottom?.let { refImgBottom.top } ?: parent.bottom)
            start.linkTo(drawableStart?.let { refImgStart.end } ?: parent.start)
            end.linkTo(drawableEnd?.let { refImgEnd.start } ?: parent.end)
        }) {
            content()
        }
        drawableTop?.let {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = it),
                contentDescription = null,
                Modifier.constrainAs(refImgTop) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(refContent.start)
                    end.linkTo(refContent.end)
                }
            )
        }
        drawableStart?.let {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = it),
                contentDescription = null,
                Modifier.constrainAs(refImgStart) {
                    top.linkTo(refContent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(refContent.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                }
            )
        }
        drawableBottom?.let {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = it),
                contentDescription = null,
                Modifier.constrainAs(refImgBottom) {
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(refContent.start)
                    end.linkTo(refContent.end)
                }
            )
        }
        drawableEnd?.let {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = it),
                contentDescription = null,
                Modifier.constrainAs(refImgEnd) {
                    top.linkTo(refContent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(refContent.bottom)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use this way:

```kotlin
DrawableWrapper(
    drawableTop = R.drawable.ic_android_orange,
    drawableStart = R.drawable.ic_android_orange,
    drawableBottom = R.drawable.ic_android_orange,
    drawableEnd = R.drawable.ic_android_orange,
) {
    Text(text = "A long Text ALL")
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: This constraint layout doesn't has a constructor which takes modifier. Any other solution?

Comment: This function would be more flexible if we provided both Text and Image as arguments and one more parameter for position of the image. It would also reduce code repetition